# Disable Items in dropdownlist by entries in database in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web application,where attendance is recorded at the gate. The users have StaffId,and will be entered by their staffId.

I am binding the dropdownlist with staffId's present in database. But I want to disable the staffid's in dropdownlist those are already checked in for the day. Can I disable items in dropdownlist after binding it with database according to the entries in other table in database? Please help.

Comment: You have to use custom html select where you have this property. Or use css and jquery to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I'll try this immidiately.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Kiran**

Set the Property of the DropDownList

**AppendDataBoundItems="true"**
so that DropDownList DataBound Event can execute.

set the Event of DropDownList

**ondatabound="DropDownList1_DataBound"**

Then execute it

```
protected void DropDownList1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    foreach (ListItem item in ((DropDownList)sender).Items)
    {
        string i = item.Value;
//Check the condition from the database whether it is Check in or not
// if check in then find out the value of user e.g userID

        if (i == "1")//instead of "1" you pass the User id who checkedIn 
        {
            item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Green;font-weight:bolder");
            item.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
    }
```